How do I populate values in same column which are null with non null values of same column on the basis of id
Example: Input Records

Output Required:

For each id, values of code1 and code2 for code3="in" should get copied to values of code1 and code2 where code3="out".
I am doing:
select distinct id from input_table where code3="in";
Applying join and taking relevant columns after joining but not getting required result.

Hi - 1) Please don't use images (as no-one can copy your data), use editable text, appropriately formatted 2) Will there only ever be one record with populated values per id? If not, will all the populated values per id be consistent?

Do you want to update that records? or a SQL to extract the result formatted as you want? Your question needs more focus

@Nifriz Yes, update records per id to make code1 and code2 columns consistent as per the values of code3="in"

@NickW All the populated values per id should be consistent.

Edited example to make it more clear.

'I am doing: select distinct id from input_table where code3="in"' why not select distinct id,code1,code2 then Applying join and taking relevant columns after joining ? BTW you are not attempting and UPDATE do you wand to UPDATE?

SELECT id,if(a.code1 = NULL,b.code1,a.code1) as code1,if(a.code2 = NULL,b.code2,a.code2) as code2,code3 FROM input_table a
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT 
id,
code1,
code2
FROM input_table
WHERE code3 = 'in'
) b ON a.id = b.id


Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

You can try this SQL replacing your_table with your table name.
UPDATE your_table AS t1
JOIN (
  SELECT id, code1, code2
  FROM your_table
  WHERE code3 = 'in'
) AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
SET t1.code1 = t2.code1, t1.code2 = t2.code2
WHERE t1.code3 = 'out' AND t1.code1 IS NULL AND t1.code2 IS NULL;


Assuming there is 1 'in' row per id, you can use Max() Over() analytic function and Coalesce() to get your expected result.
--    S a m p l e    D a t a : 
Create Table tbl ( id Int, code1 Text, code2 text, code3 text); 
Insert Into tbl 
VALUES ( 12, null, null, 'out' ),
       ( 12, null, null, 'out' ),
       ( 12, 'ABC', 'XYZ', 'in' ),
       ( 35, null, null, 'out' ),
       ( 35, null, null, 'out' ),
       ( 35, 'PQR', 'CSC', 'in' )

--      S Q L :
Select id, 
       Coalesce( code1, Max(Case When code3 = 'in' Then code1 End) 
               Over(Partition By id) ) as code1,
       Coalesce( code2, Max(Case When code3 = 'in' Then code2 End) 
               Over(Partition By id) ) as code2, 
       code3
From   tbl

/*
id  code1   code2   code3
--  ------  ------  -------
12  ABC     XYZ     out
12  ABC     XYZ     out
12  ABC     XYZ     in
35  PQR     CSC     out
35  PQR     CSC     out
35  PQR     CSC     in      */

